# Can not access to chrome extensions web page elements

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I try to access Chrome extension, Zenmate using selenium and I can get the webpage view by using id of the extension like this.

```
driver.get('chrome-extension://fdcgdnkidjaadafnichfpabhfomcebme/index.html')
```

But it gives me a view that looks zoomed in, although its not, its 100%. So I can get the first element I need but second element needed is out of frame, which is search input and can not be seen. I can see it if I make the zoom 500% and see the xpath or css selector, But even with that solution it cant find the element and i think its because of the view problem because its not viewable when page is loaded. I tried adding zoom after loading page and still no work.

This is my complete code

```
# os.system(r'start cmd /c "cd C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application & chrome.exe %s --incognito --remote-debugging-port=8989 --user-data-dir="C:\selenium\ChromeProfile"')
os.system(r'start cmd /c "cd C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application & chrome.exe %s --remote-debugging-port=8989 --user-data-dir="C:\selenium\ChromeProfile"')
opt=Options()
opt.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress","localhost:8989")
opt.page_load_strategy='none'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe",options=opt)
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get('chrome-extension://fdcgdnkidjaadafnichfpabhfomcebme/index.html')
locs='body > app-root > main > app-home > div > div.proxy-status-container > div.pt-1.location-info > div'
w(driver,15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,locs))).click()

search='/html/body/app-root/main/app-servers/div/div[1]/span[2]/i'
w(driver,15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,search))).click()

s(5)
driver.close()
```

And other issue is that I cant reach the extensions webpage although it is allowed in incognito. I can only access to webpage through non incognito mode.

Comment: Try using the pyautogui module to do crl+-, maybe.

Comment: Yeah this is what i tried already and didnt work. I assume driver needs to load eveything at first.